# The PHP script is not sending emails to my account

Tags: php, html, forms, email

Can anyone please help me with this php code. I am using a php code in my contact us page to send an email to my account. Somehow the code is not working. The basic function of this code is to capture the details inputted by an user and send the details to my email account. But somehow the PHP code is executing and not showing any error but is not sending email to my account. So, anyone please suggest me where i am going wrong... Thanks all...

Here is the PHP code which i am using:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
error_reporting (E_NONE);

$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$mob_no = $_POST['mob_no'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$course = $_POST['course'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$to = "example@mywebsite.com";
$subject = 'Request Assistance';

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset = iso-8859-1';
$headers[] = 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit';
$headers[] = 'From: ' . $first_name . " " . $last_name;

$message .= "First Name: " . $first_name . "\n";
$message .= "Last Name: " . $last_name . "\n";
$message .= "Mobile No: " . $mob_no . "\n";
$message .= "E-Mail: " . $email . "\n";
$message .= "Course: " . $course . "\n";
$message .= "Location: " . $location . "\n";
$message .= "City: " . $city . "\n";
?>



<?php
$success = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

if (($_POST['first_name'] == "") || ($_POST['last_name'] == "") || ($_POST['mob_no'] ==      "") || ($_POST['email'] == "") || ($_POST['course'] == "") || ($_POST['location'] == "") ||($_POST['city'] == "")) {
echo '<h1>Sorry for the inconvenience!</h1>';
echo '<p>We have encountered a problem, Please Note:<br />';
echo 'Make sure you fill in all the details<br />';
echo 'Do not use spaces or special characters, except in E-Mail.<br />';
echo 'Inconvenience is deeply regretted!!!</p>';
}

if ((!ctype_alpha($first_name)) || (!ctype_alpha($last_name)) || (!ctype_digit($mob_no)) || (!ctype_alpha($course)) || (!ctype_alpha($location)) || (!ctype_alpha($city))) {
echo '<h1>Sorry for the inconvenience!</h1>';
echo '<p>We have encountered a problem, Please Note:<br />';
echo 'Make sure you fill in all the details<br />';
echo 'Do not use spaces or special characters, except in E-Mail.<br />';
echo 'Inconvenience is deeply regretted!!!</p>';
}

if ($success) {
echo '<h1>Congratulations!</h1>';
echo '<p>The following message has been sent:<br /><br />';
echo '<b>To:</b> ' . $to . '<br />';
echo '<b>From:</b> ' . $email . '<br />';
echo $message;
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you write the `mail` function yourself? If so, please post your implementation.

Comment: IIRC, the email host can reject the (successfully sent) email. Several years ago, my attempt to send an email to a yahoo address resulted in the same (lack of) output you've shown. A further digging revealed a message in a log-file that indicated the email was not accepted since it came from an unknown server. The documentation for `mail` seems to confirm this - "It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination." Sorry, don't remember the name or location of the log-file. Google should though.:)

Comment: @max: `mail` is a standard PHP function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code itself doesn't look wrong to me, see following:
1. Make sure your host enables mail function
2. Using mail may result in the junk folder sometimes as many spam uses this
3. Try using phpmailer, similar to mail but more configurable